# Expression Blend + Sketchflow - Addin?

Tags: c#, xaml, expression-blend, expression-blend-5

Has anyone been able to get an extension up and running [Expression Blend + Sketchflow preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702)? I'm looking for an example project.

I was following [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75961/Building-extensions-for-Expression-Blend-4-using-M), but it is a bit outdated.

So far I:

- Created a .Net 4.5 class library project
- Added a reference to the `Microsoft.Expression.Extensibility.dll` in the new Blend Preview directory
- Set my project to deploy to the appropriate `Addins` directory
- Setup Visual Studio to run the new Blend.exe for debugging
- Hooked up MEF and inherited `IPlugin` as in the example

But my plugin doesn't seem to load and no breakpoints are hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question I decided to start working on a new version of that tutorial.

A few things to get you started right away.

I've created the basic plugin like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Microsoft.Expression.Extensibility;

namespace Demo.Extension
{
    [Export(typeof (IPackage))]
    public class Demo : IPackage
    {
        public void Load(IServices services)
        {
        }

        public void Unload()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you:

- place the plugins in **...\Blend Preview\extensions**
- run visual studio as administrator to be able to deploy to that folder during debug
- implement the IPackage instead of IPlugin

Comment: I think my real problem was that I was putting my DLL in the "Addins" folder because that folder already existed. I just set Visual Studio to deploy to "Extensions" and everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by following the demo [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2012/10/24/extending-expression-blend-4-amp-blend-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

I used the few modifications above, and put things in the `Blend Preview` directory.